# getting nonetype error with beautiful soup even though the object exists

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, nonetype

i'm trying to scrape the webpage https://www.cars.com/dealers/5374692/carvana-touchless-delivery-to-your-home/

in this page there's a button to **See All Vehicles** and i'm tring to get the href for that tag.

so far i've made this work using selenium but opening a webdriver everytime takes too much time. i don't want to try selenium

while BeautifulSoup is showing nonetype error.
my code is

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

base_url = 'https://www.cars.com/'

def request_page(url):
    session = requests.Session()
    my_headers = {"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:88.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/88.0","Accept":"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8"}
    response = session.get(url, headers=my_headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(re.sub("<!---->","", response.text), "lxml")
    return soup

def dealers_subpage(url):
    try:
        soup = request_page(url)
        descript = soup.find('dpp-update-inventory-link')
        print(descript.prettify())
        link = descript.find('a')['href']
        return base_url+str(link)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e,url)


dealers_subpage('https://www.cars.com/dealers/5374692/carvana-touchless-delivery-to-your-home/')
```

for this code i'm getting this message.

```
<dpp-update-inventory-link new-count="" party-id="74424458" used-count="100" zipcode="11763">
</dpp-update-inventory-link>

'NoneType' object is not subscriptable https://www.cars.com/dealers/5374692/carvana-touchless-delivery-to-your-home/
```

my question is why is it not reading the a tag which is present there.

***note- use incognito/private mode to visit the webpage as in normal window it redirects to some other page***

Comment: Didn't look at the site, but if it works with Selenium - probably the page uses JavaScript and with just `requests` and BS it does not render the same page you see in the browser.

Comment: The `soup.find()` looks for an element with tag `dpp-update-inventory-link` and that’s not an HTML element. Furthermore, after [wget](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/)ting the index file, I can’t find that string anywhere. Which probably explains the `None` returned by `find()`.

Comment: @Jens did you open the webpage in incognito tab.. also if you search for the tag in the page inspector it'll pop up, or inspect the see all vehicles button

Answer (score 0):

page is loading dynamic so you can not get `a` tag in `dpp-update-inventory-link` , even when you are printing `descript.prettify()` `a` is not present there so mean it rendering dynamically you have to use `selenium`.

just for  currrent requiement for link, you can generate  that link by your self because `src` for that link is using attribute of `descript` like `party-id` & `zipcode` so

```
def dealers_subpage(url):
   soup = request_page(url)
   descript = soup.find('dpp-update-inventory-link')
   party_id = descript['party-id']
   zipcode = descript['zipcode']
   url  = f"{base_url}/for-sale/searchresults.action/?dlId={party_id}&zc={zipcode}&searchSource=CAPTIVE_BLENDED"
   return url
```

Comment: although it is not what i asked but your solution works so good. thanks bro